# Rotate A object when user swipe left to right on specific area

Tags: android

[here my ui image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GjOeJ.jpg)  
I want to rotate a image view when user swipe left to right on specific area.
How calculate rotation speed from swipe left to right and rotation stopped angle.

```
    GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener simpleOnGestureListener = new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {


                float sensitvity = 50;


                if ((e2.getX() - e1.getX()) > sensitvity) {


                    float x_velocity = velocityX;

                    rotate((x_velocity));

                }


                return super.onFling(e1, e2, velocityX, velocityY);
            }
        };

        final GestureDetector gestureDetector
                = new GestureDetector(simpleOnGestureListener);


        swipeLayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
                return true;
            }
        });




private void rotate(double xVelocity) {


        double rotateangle = xVelocity / 12.56 * 360;
        rotateangle = Math.round(xVelocity);
        RotateAnimation rotateAnimation = new RotateAnimation(0, rotateangle , Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
        DecimalFormat twoDForm = new DecimalFormat("##");
        xVelocity = Double.valueOf(twoDForm.format(xVelocity));

        if (xVelocity > 0) {
            if (xVelocity > 1000) {

                double i = (int) (xVelocity / 1000);


                DecimalFormat twoDForm1 = new DecimalFormat("##");
                i = Double.valueOf(twoDForm1.format(i));
                rotateAnimation.setRepeatCount((int) i);
                rotateAnimation.setDuration((long) i * 100);
                rotateAnimation.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
            } else {
                rotateAnimation.setDuration(1000);
            }

        } else {
            rotateAnimation.setDuration(1000);
        }

        rotateAnimation.setFillAfter(true);

        raotate.startAnimation(rotateAnimation);
    }
```

This is my code for spin a image view but its not work properly so please tell me how calculate swipe speed,stop angle under 360 degrees.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GjOeJ.jpg)

Comment: use `GestureDetector` and `OnGestureListener#onScroll`

Comment: i do that but rotation not work smoothly...can i send u my code if u dont mind

Comment: if i dont mind? how else i could tell anything?

Comment: sorry, but i am new on android so..

Comment: Put your code here.

Comment: banking - only one fingue

Comment: @pskink - yes sir

Comment: start with [this](https://pastebin.com/UuNGSYt5) then

Comment: thanx ,its working